# How to securely call a Google Cloud Run service from Java Script?

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

We plan to build a web client (Angular) for our project. Our Backend will be a lot of google cloud run services. How can we make sure that these services can only be called by this web application? 
I understand that there are Service Account, which I can use to limit access to Cloud Run services, but how do I do that in a purely JavaScript application and without a logged in user. I just want to authenticate the application not the user.
Any advise or samples?

Comment: When you say "Javascript",  you mean a website? Or a backend in Node? Do you know the users beforehand? If so, do they have a Google account?

Comment: Yes, I mean a website and yes I know the users, but the question is can I restrict access to the run services even before a user logs in. So only allow this webclient is allowed to access the services at all. Is there something like "application authorization" before I do authentication. To make this simpler, can I somehow assign a service account to a website and this service account has the role "service invoker" on my service. So only a website with this service is account can call my run service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: The application authentication and authorization level is managed by service account. But putting a service account key file in your Javascript app (and thus viewable by any user in their browser) is useless because your secret becomes public!

---

With Cloud Run, you have 2 mode: private and public

If public, no security, all the requests go to your Cloud Run service

If private, Google Front End check the identity of the requester and if they have the run.invoker permission. If so, the request pass through, else it's blocked.

For being authenticated, today, you need a service account. If you aren't on Google Cloud Platform (here in the browser of the users for example), you need a service account key file. But, if you put it in your website, it's not secure because anyone can take it and use it outside your website.

So, today, you can't do this: Either your Cloud Run is public, without any check, or private with authentication (and IAM authorization)

But, soon, at least in 2020 I hope, you should be able to put a load balancer in front of Cloud Run and to activate IAP on it. Thus, the users will be authenticated thanks to their Google account authentication cookie (SSO). However, in private mode in your browser, the user will be asked for being authenticated before going to the website. It's not authentication free, it's just authentication not manage by your own.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Actually the possibility of putting Cloud Run Services behind a Firewall on which I could configure allowed IP ranges, would be enough for our use. case. Still looking forward to the IAP solution.
On question still remains. I can still protect my services by assigning user roles as invokers right? So my website is public, but the user can only call run services if logged in with an account that is assigned to a certain service as invoker. Or is this also not possible?

Comment: There is nothing in public beta for this today.

Comment: Ok. So I have follow up question. Would it be possible to run a Compute Engine with NGINX to host our Webclient, which uses a service account file to authenticate, but put that Compute Engine behind a firewall so only our staff could access it? Is that an option or a very stupid idea?

Comment: With compute engine and network tool you can do all what you did in the "old world", traditional datacenter. Thus yes, you can. But, be careful: you service isn't resilient, scalable, regional HA. You have to install  you own SSL certificate and perform much more stuffs than a managed service. Maybe, a better solution (but also more expensive) is to deploy a GKE cluster with the Cloud Run Addon on it for having the exact same Cloud Run experience. (Cloud Run on Anthos -> marketing name) And then, easily switch back to managed Cloud Run with the features has been released.

Comment: That sounds great! Thank you!